# Altering a regex float expression to enforce a leading number before decimal point

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following regex expression that validates via jquery a textbox element in html.

> /^-?\d*[.]?\d*$/

I would like to alter this so that the decimal point can **only** be added if it has a leading number before it.

If someone could provide me the solution I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Are you sure you want to match `"23."` and don't want to match a string within a larger string (e.g., "The fish I caught weighted 23.7 kg.")?

Comment: Why do you insist on a leading zero before a decimal point? JavaScript is "happy" without one too ... My suggestion would be to echo on your page in some form how you read the input and do that **with** a leading zero.

Comment: Before rushing into presenting your code you should state the problem in words, followed by an example or two, showing for each whether it is OK or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `+` quantifier after first `\d`

```
^-?\d+[.]?\d*$
```

```js
const n1 = '.1';
const n2 = '0.1';
const n3 = '-0.1';
const regex = /^-?\d+[.]?\d*$/;

console.log(`${n1}  ==> ${regex.test(n1)}`);
console.log(`${n2} ==> ${regex.test(n2)}`);
console.log(`${n3} ==> ${regex.test(n3)}`);
```

#### Edit:

Above pattern will match strings that have no digits after the decimal such as `"1."`. If you want to enforce digits after decimal if decimal is present, use following regex

```
^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

```js
const n1 = '1.';
const n2 = '1.1';
const regex = /^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/;

console.log(`${n1}  ==> ${regex.test(n1)}`);
console.log(`${n2} ==> ${regex.test(n2)}`);
```

Comment: so replace the '*' with a '+'?

Comment: it's not allowing me to enter a negitive sign as first character

Comment: I think this would be better `^[-]?\d+([.]\d+)?$`

Comment: @acbay although OP didn't specify whether strings such as `1.` should be matched or not but i think its worth including in the answer. Answer updated. Thank you.

Comment: No no, your answer was completely answers the question and Im aware that its not asked specifically, I just wanted to help Hank a little bit more. Thank you.